# Dockerized stackdriver agent - payloadErrors in logs

Tags: collectd, google-cloud-stackdriver

We have dockerized the stackdriver agent and using /proc volume from base host to monitor processes. In the collectd.log, we are frequently getting below error:

Any clues on this issue?

```
    [2017-12-13 07:07:26] write_gcm: Server response (CollectdTimeseriesRequest) contains errors:
{
  "payloadErrors": [
    {
      "index": 218,
      "error": {
        "code": 3,
        "message": "Expected 4 labels. Found 0. Mismatched labels for payload [values {\n  data_source_name: \"value\"\n  data_source_type: GAUGE\n  value {\n    double_value: 483561472\n  }\n}\nstart_time {\n  seconds: 1513148845\n  nanos: 819266918\n}\nend_time {\n  seconds: 1513148845\n  nanos: 819266918\n}\nplugin: \"processes\"\nplugin_instance: \"all\"\ntype: \"ps_rss\"\n] on resource [type: \"gce_instance\"\nlabels {\n  key: \"instance_id\"\n  value: \"504805423291753409\"\n}\nlabels {\n  key: \"zone\"\n  value: \"europe-west1-b\"\n}\n] for project XXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and contacted Google Cloud Support. They told me that the Stackdriver service has been updated recently to accept more detailed information on `ps_rss` metrics, but it has caused metrics from older agents to not be sent at all.

You should be able to fix this issue by [upgrading your Stackdriver agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) to the latest version. I recently updated, and haven't seen the issue since.